# What species is this marine invertebrate sighted 2m below the surface near Halifax, NS?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, marine-biology, invertebrates

This image was taken at ~2m depth, with a small ROV in Halifax, NS in May. We're in the Northwest Atlantic Ocean and as far as I know, don't have gooseneck barnacles.

Considering that it may be a polychaete worm as several other species were sighted during same dive (*Tomopteris ?*, *Chaetopterus*) and the fan appears to have more than 10 appendages. Possibly a sabellid or goblin worm?

Sizing is difficult to estimate but ~5cm in length.

[image: unidentified translucent object in ocean]

Adjusted, enlarged version:
[image]